# Is there any way to send a text reply to call that I couldn't receive?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-435

If I couldn't receive a call due to any reason an automatic reply saying 'I am in a meeting' should be sent to caller without my any interaction.
Is there any option in windows phone? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 for phones does have a 'text reply' feature but the user **must** interact.

There's no automatic setting because it would be easy to abuse - if you were to receive many marketing calls, each automatic 'text reply' would cost you money, and this would add up over time.

Comment: good point about automatic